# API RequestEnvelope returns html

Tags: soap, docusignapi

Submitted SOAP request to get envelope information using API RequestEnvelope.  The response was successful but only returned HTML.  No information about the envelope and its documents.

Comment: Please see this page in order to get better responses to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Typically that happens when you are calling the incorrect URL. Make sure you have https as opposed to http in the URL you are calling. I believe the WSDL is actually missing the s in the URLs so if you load it into something like SOAP UI you have to change it yourself.